# Create a new table by joining two tables having common column names with matching data type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to create a new table "c" from table "a" and "b". The columns for table "c" should be the columns which are common between table "a" and "b" and have matching data type as well.

Suppose the table structure is as below -

| Table a | Table b |
| --- | --- |
| col1 : int | col1 : int |
| col2 : string | col2 : string |
| col3 : string | col3 : int |
| col4 : string | col5 : string |

The output should have below columns -

| Table c |
| --- |
| col1 : int |
| col2 : string |

From data POV, the input and output should look like this -
TABLE A

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | ABC | DEF | GHI |

TABLE B

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | ABC | 6 | GHI |

TABLE C or output table

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | ABC |

The Pseudo code I am working with is -

```
val df1Cols = df1.columns.toSet
val df2Cols = df2.columns.toSet
val commonCols = df1Cols.intersect(df2Cols)

val commonColExtract = df1.schema.filter(field => commonCols.contains(field.name)).map(field => field.name).toList()

Output dataframe :
val df = df1.join(df2, commonColExtract, "inner")
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output with some data to produce a [mcve]. Are there any keys in the two tables on which they can be joined? Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: I have updated my question. The common keys have to be extracted from the dataframes only. If the column name and data type match, those will be the joining columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive `commonColExtract`, you need to compare both the column names as well as the data type of the column.

```
val df1Cols = df1.schema.map(c => (c.name, c.dataType.simpleString))
//df1Cols: Seq[(String, String)] = List((col1,int), (col2,string), (col3,string), (col4,string))

val df2Cols = df2.schema.map(c => (c.name, c.dataType.simpleString))
//df2Cols: Seq[(String, String)] = List((col1,int), (col2,string), (col3,int), (col5,string))

val commonColExtract = df1Cols.intersect(df2Cols).map(_._1)
//commonColExtract: Seq[String] = List(col1, col2)
```

Then you can join with `commonColExtract`:

```
df1.join(df2, commonColExtract, "inner").select(commonColExtract.head, commonColExtract.tail: _*).show

//+----+----+
//|col1|col2|
//+----+----+
//|   5| ABC|
//+----+----+
```

You can `alias` `df1` and `df2` if you want to select columns from a specific dataframe.